# Cost of kernel's PAE option

Tags: linux-kernel

I am making a kernel(4.4) for 32bit(above i686) processors.
I guess almost 32bit PC has under 4GB RAM, but some PC has more than 4GB RAM.
So I consider about PAE kernel option.
But there is a cost. 
like below...

CONFIG_X86_PAE: PAE is required for NX support, and furthermore enables larger swapspace support for non-overcommit purposes. It has the cost of more pagetable lookup **overhead**, and also consumes more **pagetable space per** process.

I can understand roughly.
But I can't feel excatly.
How big are the overhead and the pagetable space?

Comment: To get exact values, measure it.

Answer (score 0):

PAE is useful on x86 CPUs which are 32-bit but actually have an address bus of > 32 bit say like 40-bit. So they can actually access more memory. Now to deal with all this extra space the kernel has a larger page table hierarchy. So extra lookup and hence extra cost.